# Expected value of i.i.d samples

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am trying to understand estimator bias and was a little perplexed by this example.<sup>[src)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQFcE.png)</sup>

$$ \mathbb{E}[\overline{x}] = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i\right]=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\mathbb{E}[x]=\frac{1}{N}\cdot N\cdot\mathbb{E}[x]=\mathbb{E}[x]=\mu. $$

Why does $\sum^m_{i=1}\mathbb{E}[x_i] = m\mu$? No explanation was given other than the fact that the data samples $\{ x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m\}$ are i.i.d.

Comment: Im sorry the image isn't embedded in my question, I cant do that until I have 10 reputation.

Comment: That follows from the assumption that $x_i$'s are identically distributed, because the expectation of a random variable depends only on its distribution.

Comment: @SangchulLee But in this equation doesnt $x_i$ represent a single value in the sample set?

Comment: I am not familiar with statistician's practice, but i.i.d. sample usually means a sequence of independent and identically distributed *random variables*.

Comment: I see, unfortunately this might have been due to my misunderstanding of the notation. Thank you for your help!